# Planned Contrasts on glmmTMB

Tags: r, comparison, mixed-models

Apologies if this is a repeat question. Many have posted looking looking for a way to do post-hoc analyses on the conditional model (fixed factors) in glmmTMB. I want to do plannned contrasts between certain groups, not test every pairwise comparison (e.g. Tukey).

The code below worked well on nlme:lme for a lmm. However, it returns an error on the code below.

```
Error in modelparm.default(model, ...) : 
  dimensions of coefficients and covariance matrix don't match
```

Is there a way to do planned contrasts on a glmmTMB?

```
#filtdens is a dataframe and TRT,DATE,BURN,VEG are factors
filtdens <- merged %>% filter(!BLOCK %in% c("JB2","JB4","JB5") & MEAS =="DENS" & 
                      group == "TOT" & BURN == "N" & VEG == "C")
filtdens$TD <- interaction(filtdens$TRT, filtdens$DATE)
mod2 <- glmmTMB(count~(TD)+(1|BLOCK),
                 data=filtdens,
        zi=~1,
        family=nbinom1(link = "log"))

k1 <- matrix(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,

       0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,

       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0,

       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1), byrow = T, ncol = 12)

summary(glht(mod2, linfct=k1),test=adjusted("bonferroni"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reproducible example would be helpful, but: [this vignette](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/blob/master/glmmTMB/vignettes/model_evaluation.rmd) in the development version offers code that ought to enable `multcomp::linfct`, i.e.:

```
glht_glmmTMB <- function (model, ..., component="cond") {
    glht(model, ...,
         coef. = function(x) fixef(x)[[component]],
         vcov. = function(x) vcov(x)[[component]],
         df = NULL)
}
modelparm.glmmTMB <- function (model, 
                               coef. = function(x) fixef(x)[[component]],
                               vcov. = function(x) vcov(x)[[component]],
                               df = NULL, component="cond", ...) {
    multcomp:::modelparm.default(model, coef. = coef., vcov. = vcov.,
                        df = df, ...)
}
```

Test (this example is with Tukey, but I don't see why it shouldn't work more generally ...)

```
library(glmmTMB)
data("cbpp",package="lme4")
cbpp_b1 <- glmmTMB(incidence/size~period+(1|herd),
               weights=size,family=binomial,
               data=cbpp)
g1 <- glht(cbpp_b1, linfct = mcp(period = "Tukey"))
summary(g1)
```

This works with the current CRAN version, but the current *development* version of `glmmTMB` offers more options (e.g. `emmeans()`; see the above-linked vignette).  You'll need to install via `devtools::install_github("glmmTMB/glmmTMB/glmmTMB")` (you'll need compilation tools installed as well).

Comment: Thanks, Ben, for this and all the other work you do.

Comment: For those having compatibility issues between compatibility issues between R3.5.1. and Rtools3.5 when running devtools, this fixes the problem: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rtools-not-recognized-r3-5-1-rtools-3-5/11311

Comment: With `glht` I get the error `Error in glht.matrix(fitUSA, linfct = B) : 
  ‘ncol(linfct)’ is not equal to ‘length(coef(model))’` and with `glht_glmmTMB` I get the error ` Error in glht.matrix(model, ..., coef. = function(x) fixef(x)[[component]],  : 
  ‘ncol(linfct)’ is not equal to ‘length(coef(model))’ `. I have tried with `linfct = B`, where B is a matrix (like `k1` above) with so many rows as fixed effect estimates in model and 1 column or 2 columns, but both options produce me the same error.

Comment: I had to try in that way, because I do not want to contrast 2 categories of same factor, but two distinct variables

Comment: @iago, could you post a reproducible example as a new question?

Comment: Already posted, Ben. Thank you. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62252468/contrast-between-variables-in-glmmtmb