# post-hoc custom contrasts - glmmTMB with poly()

Tags: r, mixed-models, posthoc

I need to figure out how to run a set of custom contrasts for a `glmmTMB` model with a polynomial predictor. I followed the answer [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886334/planned-contrasts-on-glmmtmb) for allowing `glht` to work with the`glmmTMB` model, but I'm still failing, seemingly at two stages:
1) how do I define the contrasts for a polynomial predictor? I need to use the list() approach, since my actual model is quite complex and I'll definitely mess up the `matrix` approach
2) once the contrasts are set up - how do I run them for `glmmTMB` specifically?

```
library(contrast)
library(glmmTMB)

set.seed(1)
df <- structure(list(x = 1:20, y = c(4L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 23L, 21L, 42L, 
56L, 70L, 80L, 95L, 120L, 152L, 187L, 224L, 280L, 326L, 374L, 
438L, 500L), z = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), class = "factor", .Label = "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

#just a toy example with a linear model and no poly()
m <- lm(y ~ x * z, data = df)
contrast(m, 
        a = list(x = 1, z = "a"),
        b = list(x = 10, z = "b"))

# a (big) simplification of what I'm after:
m1 <- glmmTMB(y ~ poly(x, 3) * z + (1|group), data = df, family = poisson)
contrast(m1, 
        a = list(x = 1, z = "a"),
        b = list(x = 10, z = "b"))
```

EDIT
One addition - since my actual model is zero-inflated, how does this approach handle that? I'm only interested in testing the "response" values (i.e., combined zero-inflation and counts).